# Cannot remove git repository completely

Tags: windows, git, git-remote

I have been using git on windows-msysgit. Whenever I try to remove a repository completely either using explorer or using

```
$ git rm -rf ptp/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

it errors out "The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid" or the fatal error above.

What's wrong with me/git?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the windows restart help? :)

Comment: No! It is still there. I can only rename the parent folder but cannot remove the file ta05636 with size of 0 bytes.

Is this a measure Microsoft takes against Git? :)

Comment: Loading Windows in Safe mode and erasing will definately 'fix' this issue. Some process in your normal startup is accessing that file and Windows isn't allowing you to erase it. Using safe mode, you will basically limit which processes start up, thus allowing you to delete it. If the process STILL starts up in safe mode, you might have to boot your computer with a linux LIVE disc (pick your flavor) and delete it that way...

Comment: `Knoppix` is a good choice. http://www.knoppix.net/

Comment: `Live Mint` is also a great choice! http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=65

Answer (score 16):

To remove a git repo, just do `rm -rf ptp/`.  That's it.
`git rm` is used to move items from the index [the staging area for changes / new files], not to delete git repositories.

Comment: +1, but be warned -- git rm *will* delete files from your working directory, provided they are also removed from the index, and have no unstaged or staged changes. Fortunately, in these cases you can always get them back from the version history.

Comment: No way!
$ rm -rf ptp/
rm: cannot remove directory `ptp/.git': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `ptp': Directory not empty

And got that:
hoppala@HOPPALANINYERI /d/Projects/ptp/ptp/.git
$ ls
ta05636

hoppala@HOPPALANINYERI /d/Projects/ptp/ptp/.git
$ rm -rf ta05636

hoppala@HOPPALANINYERI /d/Projects/ptp/ptp/.git
$ ls
ta05636

Comment: That's definitely odd. This probably has more to do with some problem on Windows, rather than with git itself.

Comment: Right. I think Win7 is the culprit.

Comment: this is most probably a permission issue or process locking the directory. got the same problem here at MacOSX

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the git repository on Windows do this:

Win+R, Type `cmd`, Enter.

```
> cd c:/path/to/parent/of/ptp-repo
> rmdir /S /Q ptp
```

Or if it fails then check [who locks the directory](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) and delete it by hands from Explore.

Most likely **some process holds a lock** on files/dirs in your repo.

Comment: Here is the outcome :(
D:\Projects\ptp>rmdir /S /Q ptp
ptp\GIT~1\ta05636 - The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.

I tried WhoLockMe but it chrashed as I am using Win7. Is there any other way to discover 'the locker'?

Comment: I used Unlocker. It says there is no locking handler on the folder :s It didnt remove the file even though I went with 'delete on the next restart' option.

Comment: Explorer won't display the .git folder and rmdir says that it isn't allowed because the folder isn't empty...

Answer (score 2):

I tried to remove GIT on my windows-XP, by means of the Windows/Configuration/Software menu. After some error message (which I cannot remember), it removed all files. I checked it, and there are no files with ptp in the name left on the entire system.

A problem remained however: each time I opened windows-explorer, a nasty error message came calling for a dll file that wasn't there anymore.

When checking the registry, there were many traces to GIT left in the registry. I removed them carefully by hand, which seems to have solved the problem. This is of course a dangerous path, but I had no choice. Perhaps it is a good idea to look into the Windows-deinstallation script very carefully.

Stef Joosten

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, try running cygwin console as admin and rm -rf the dir.

Answer (score 0):

I have also just experienced this odd problem on windows 10: An empty .git folder simply would not delete and a restart of windows did not remedy it, nor did `rmdir .git`, nor did `rm -rf .git`.

Similarly to another suggestion, I used ubuntu (instead of cygwin) for windows (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0) and issued an `rm -rf .git`, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This solution should make it possible to delete any locked files and folders without installing any new programs:

1. Go to your **Resource Monitor** (in the ***Task Manager***)
2. Go to the **CPU** tab
3. **Search** for your file in the "**Associated Handles**"
4. Now you'll see which process(es) are locking your file (it's likely *explorer.exe*)
5. **Close those processes**   (be careful, this might delete unsaved work)
6. **Delete** your previously locked files, this should work without a problem now.
7. *Optional:* Start processes again (for explorer.exe: Go to Task Manager, File → New task → type in "explorer.exe")

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

On Git Bash do:

```
$ git remote remove <name>
```

To see your remote list:

```
$ git remote
```

Answer (score -1):

When I want to remove a GIT repo on Windows... i very simply delete (or move) the .git directory where the repo sits... I do this straight from Explorer... it hasn't failed me yet!

Answer (score -2):

I have a third partition, on a dual boot with Windows 7 and Fedora Linux, and I realized I had a file open in vim in a terminal, and that was causing a `.fuse_hidden...` file to not be deletable.

When I closed the file in vim, I was able to delete the `.git` directory.