# Git Folder deleted, but not gone

Tags: git, github

I wanted to remove a Git folder from my computer so without going into the git console, I deleted the folder using the Windows FS. Whenever I boot up the git console however, I realize that the Git folder that I just deleted still exists. It is not on my computer that I can see, and every time I try to run "rm -r FolderName", it pops up a message asking if I am sure I want to remove a write protected file with

```
"rm: remove write-protected file 'Folder/.git/objects/34/33535dg3e4t'?"
```

This would be fine, but there are thousands of them, and I am not going to sit there all day typing "y". I also try to type

```
"git rm -r FolderName"
```

but this command does not work and it says

```
"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `rm -rf FolderName`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
yes | rm -r FolderName
```

I usually prefer this approach, because I just type `Ctrl+A` to go to the beginning of the command prompt, then type `yes |`, which is faster than going back to write the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was run

```
rm -rf ptp/ FolderName
```

[Cannot remove git repository completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384057/cannot-remove-git-repository-completely)